# Receive Salesforce Platform Events in Datadog

Tags: events, salesforce, datadog

I have a Salesforce environment and a Datadog environment. I would like to make Datadog receives events that are sent by a custom Salesforce platform event.

I've already tried the out-of-the-box Datadog integration with [Salesforce](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/salesforce/), but it only captures the standard events like login, logout, etc. and I need to capture the custom events that I create in Salesforce.

I also know that is possible to send an event to Datadog using the Datadog API, but I don't wanna make api requests from Salesforce.

Someone know a way to do it?